# How can I fix this ERROR MESSAGE" unique constraint"?

Tags: sql, database, runtime-error

```
create table Store_Owner1
(
    phone_number number(10) not null,
    f_name varchar(10),
    last_name varchar(10),
    OwnerID number(10) primary key,
    Email varchar(10) 
);

insert into Store_Owner1 (phone_number, f_name, last_name, OwnerID, Email) 
values (0258744169, 'WAFA', 'ALOUFI', 0563224789, 'WAFA@GMAIL.com');

ALTER table Store_Owner1
MODIFY Email varchar (35);

select * from Store_Owner1;
------------------------------------------------

RUN
PHONE_NUMBER    F_NAME  LAST_NAME   OWNERID       EMAIL
258744169        WAFA    ALOUFI    563224789    WAFA@GMAIL.com
```

Everything is okay when I do "select" but when I run the insert statement, I got an error

> ORA-00001: unique constraint

Everything Bidou is in its correct place, but I do not know why this error appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`primary key` implies that column needs to be unique. If you tried to insert the same `OwnerId` again, it will throw that error.

If it is in fact valid to have duplicate for `OwnerId` in this table, you can make some new primary key; it can even be an auto-generated uuid in many databases.